# Phonegap (Cordova) error at CompileXIB

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm having some problems with CompileXIB at Cordova.

System Information:
OS X Yosemite Beta 10.10
XCode 6 Beta 5

Everytime I try to run **cordova build ios** the terminal just "freeze" at this part:

```
CompileXIB ToGo/Classes/MainViewController.xib
    cd /Applications/mampstack-5.4.15-0/apache2/htdocs/toGo_app/platforms/ios
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/yeltsin/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Users/yeltsin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/Users/yeltsin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/Users/yeltsin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Users/yeltsin/.rvm/bin:/Developer/android/sdk/platform-tools:/Developer/android/sdk/tools"
    export XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH=/Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
    /Applications/Xcode6-Beta5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --target-device iphone --target-device ipad --errors --warnings --notices --module ToGo --minimum-deployment-target 6.0 --output-partial-info-plist /Applications/mampstack-5.4.15-0/apache2/htdocs/toGo_app/platforms/ios/build/ToGo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ToGo.build/MainViewController-PartialInfo.plist --auto-activate-custom-fonts --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Applications/mampstack-5.4.15-0/apache2/htdocs/toGo_app/platforms/ios/build/emulator/ToGo.app/MainViewController.nib /Applications/mampstack-5.4.15-0/apache2/htdocs/toGo_app/platforms/ios/ToGo/Classes/MainViewController.xib
```

Doesn't shows an error. Just don't proceed. I tried with this project and with another one and both are having the same problems.

How can I fix this? :(

Thanks,
Yeltsin

Comment: I had the same problem, do you have the non-beta Xcode installed as well? If not, it may be worth getting that from the app store and seeing you still run into this problem.

Comment: @nihiser post a "answer the question" so I can mark your answer as correct :)

Comment: answer posted, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to make sure that you have the non-Beta Xcode installed, otherwise you will continue to get this error.